# Why can't traits have parameters with Context Bounds

Tags: scala, generics

Here :ClassTag : TypeTag base class definitions are not allowed on traits as they are considered as Context Bounds

I can make it Abstract Class but I loose the benefit of multi-inheritance

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

trait DataProcessor[T <: Product : ClassTag : TypeTag, U <: Product : ClassTag : TypeTag] {
  def performAnalysis(inputDs: Dataset[T]): Dataset[U]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the fact that Scala doesn't allow a trait to receive arguments as they don't have a constructor (this might [change in the upcoming future](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/trait-parameters.html)). An expansion of context bounds is to add implicit parameters to the definition. Thus, you're actually trying to write:

```
trait DataProcessor[T <: Product, U <: Product](implicit ev: ClassTag[T], ev1: TypeTag[U], ...)
```

Instead, you can require them as [abstract type members](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/abstract-type-members.html) on the trait:

```
trait DataProcessor[T <: Product, U <: Product] {
  def typeTagU: TypeTag[U]
  def clsTagU: ClassTag[U]
  def typeTagT: TypeTag[T]
  def clsTagT: ClassTag[T]

  def performAnalysis(inputDs: Dataset[T]): Dataset[U]
}
```

Or, as Luis mentioned, move the implicits to where you actually require them, at the method level:

```
def performAnalysis(inputDs: Dataset[T])(implicit ev: ClassTag[T], ev1: TypeTag[T]): Dataset[U]
```

Comment: Other solution would be to move the context bounds _(and thus the implicit arguments)_ to the method call instead of the `trait` definition.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez That's actually an even better idea.